# GameObjects showing up in Hierachy, but are invisible in the camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was following [this tutorial](https://thesehallways.wordpress.com/2017/09/07/create-a-chessboard-with-2d-arrays/) on creating a 2D chessboard. Everything kinda worked, my squares are showing up as GameObject in the Hierachy, but I can't see them in the camera, only their hitboxes. I double checked everything, but everything seems right. Maybe there is a setting, which wasn't mentioned in the tutorial, which i have to change? If any additional data/information is needed, let me know (all code is below).

This is the scene when pressing play:
[image: This is the scene when pressing play]

This is my square prefab:
[image]
[image]

And the GameManager gameObject:
[image]

Board.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Board : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tilePrefab;

    public GameObject pawnPrefab, knightPrefab, bishopPrefab, rookPrefab, queenPrefab, kingPrefab;

    public Material whiteMat, blackMat;
    public Material whitePieceMat, blackPieceMat;

    public GameObject[,] squares = new GameObject[8, 8];
    [HideInInspector]
    public static string[] alphabet = new string[] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"};

    public void CreateBoard()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                squares [i, j] = Instantiate (tilePrefab, new Vector3 (i, j, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                
                if (i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 != 0 || i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0) 
                {
                    squares [i, j].GetComponent<Renderer>().material = blackMat;
                } 
                
                else 
                {
                    squares [i, j].GetComponent<Renderer>().material = whiteMat;
                }
                
                squares [i, j].transform.SetParent (gameObject.transform);
                squares [i, j].name = alphabet [i] + (j + 1);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

GameManager.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Board board;
    void Start()
    {
        board = gameObject.GetComponent<Board>();
        board.CreateBoard();
    }
}
```

Comment: your code looks right . We need a screenshot of the hierarchy and scene view of the prefab in Unity (doubleclick on the prefab). Are there any errors or warnings in the console? Does the prefab have a renderer component?

Comment: Be sure what z axis you are making the objects on and where the camera is pointing.

Comment: @Hacky The console is empty and the Prefab has a "Sprite Renderer" component. I added some screenshots.

Comment: What happens if you don't apply the material? Can you view the sprite from behind? Is the default layer in the culling mask of the camera? Maybe the sprites need some sort of sprite shader instead of standard shader.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. If I don't apply the material they show up. I don't know whats wrong with my materials yet, but i might figure that out. Thanks a lot

Comment: In case it is using UI stuff make sure it is somewhere nested below a `Canvas` ! Otherwise they will just not be rendered at all.

Comment: Also are you sure the colors are not maybe transparent?

Answer (score 2):

i have had a similar issue in 3D and here is few tips for things you may want to look for;
1: the clipping of the camera - If the clipping is too small the gameobject wont show to the camera when rendered
2: the normals of the sprite - If the normal is facing the other way of the camera the sprite will be invisible

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the material is ok, this would be one of the reasons why the objects are not visible.
As #Hacky said, the code looks correct, it would be ok to give us more information, some screenshots with the hierarchy and prefab.

Comment: I added some screenshots of important objects.

Comment: ok, like I said, most likely the problem is in the material. Try not to set any material.
instead: squares [i, j].GetComponent<Renderer>().material = blackMat;
use this: squares [i, j].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = color.Black;

Comment: to make sure there is a problem with the material, you can set your material "black" directly in the prefab editor, and you can see if it is visible or not.

Comment: But I assure you 100% that the problem is in the material.

Comment: Yup I just confirmed that the problem is the material. Changing the material in the Inspector later doesn't change anything.

Comment: OK, i tried to create a material directly from the Sprites Shader (I tthink i missunderstood the utotial before) but I get the following error and can't even create one: `Material Preset cannot be created from a material that is located outside the project.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
TMPro.EditorUtilities.TMP_ContextMenus:DuplicateMaterial(MenuCommand) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.1.1/Scripts/Editor/TMPro_ContextMenus.cs:57)`